# Timeout handling in dotnet core API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.2, timeoutexception

My angular application is consuming dotnet core API. My API is comsuming other APIs to send response. Sometimes, the other APIs I'm consuming takes too long to respond.
Thus, I dont want my angular application to keeps waiting for too long. I want to create a *timeout middleware* which returns, i dont know, a response saying "Request Timeout" or something for all the requests that takes more than 3-4 seconds.

I'm using dotnet core 2.2.

Comment: You could implement a BackgroundService to implement longer tasks. I know it is not what you asked for. It is just my personal suggestion.